# Qual a melhor forma de transformar um formulário de contacto seguro?

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho um formulário de contacto a funcionar mas acusa falha de segurança de crossscripting no sitelock. Alguma ajuda com ultrapassar o problema?
Obrigado

```
<?php
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

            if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


                // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

                $email_to = "mail que recebe";

                $email_subject = "Mensagem vindo do site";


                $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required 
                $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
                                $telephone_from = $_POST['telephone']; // required
                $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
                $comments = $_POST['message']; // required

                $email_message = "Mensagem vindo do site\n\n";


                function clean_string($string) {
                    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
                }


                $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Email Address: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
                                $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone_from)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


                // create email headers

                $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

                'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

                ?>



                <?php

                }

                ?>
```

```
<form id="contact-form" action="contact.php" name="contactform" class="row" method="post">
<div id="input_name" class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="name" class="form-control triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="bounceIn" placeholder="Nome">
</div>
<div id="input_telephone" class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" class="form-control triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="bounceIn" placeholder="Telefone">
</div>
<div id="input_email" class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="bounceIn" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div id="input_subject" class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="bounceIn" placeholder="Assunto">
</div>
<div id="input_message" class="col-md-12">
<textarea class="form-control triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="bounceIn" name="message" id="comments" rows="6" placeholder="Gostaria de ser contactado(a) para mais informações"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="form_btn" class="col-md-12">
<div class="text-center">
<div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
          data-sitekey=""
            data-callback="onSubmit"
          data-size="invisible">
 <script>onload();</script>


<input type="submit" value="Quero ser contactado(a)" id="submit" class="btn btn-theme triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="bounceIn"> 
</div>                                
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="CSRF" value="<?= $_SESSION['CSRF'] ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Falta o CSRF Token, possivelmente seja isso. Mas, o parâmetro $headers é extremamente perigoso, um atacante pode simplesmente inserir um "\r\n" e inserir quaisquer informações. Você deve, pelo menos remover o "\r\n", uma vez que esta é a forma (CRLF) com que cada header adicional é dividido.

Answer (score 4):

> *Não garanto que esta resposta corrija todos os problemas, pode ainda haver outros problemas de segurança!*

---

Esta é a função:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

O que ocorre é EXATAMENTE nos dois últimos parâmetros do `mail()`, que é o `$additional_headers` e o `$additional_parameters`, este quinto parâmetro é ainda pior e nem irei falar dele.

O `$additional_headers` informa os cabeçalhos dividos por um CRLF (`\r\n`) exatamente como você está fazendo ao final de cada linha.

---

### Como atacar:

Como o ataque funciona, a melhor forma de se proteger é saber como exatamente o ataque funciona.

Isto é o que você tem:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 
           'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Observe que se o valor do `$email_from` for:

`meu@email.com\r\nBcc:seu@email.com`

Ele irá fazer com que:

```
$headers = 'From: meu@email.com\r\n'.
            Bcc:seu@email.com\r\n'.   // <<<
           'Reply-To: meu@email.com\r\n'.
           'Bcc:seu@email.com\r\n" .  // <<<                     
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Isto será o resultado.

---

**Prova:**

```
curl ^
-X POST ^
-d "first_name=Nome&telephone=123456789&email=meu@email.com%0ACc:seu@email.com&subject=teste3&message=teste3" ^
https://seu-link.com
```

Observe exatamente o valor do `email`, ele é o importante:

```
email=meu@email.com%0ACc:email-de@outra-pessoa.com
```

Isto irá fazer com que o campo de `email` seja igual ao `meu@email.com` com o `%0A` que é o `CR` em [HTML URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) (ou `%0D%0A`) e por fim `Cc:seu@email.com`.

Com isto uma outra pessoa também irá receber o e-mail, que inclusive pode mencionar mais de uma.

---

Mas porque o `clean_string` não funciona para remover o `Cc` que usou? Simples, ele é case-sensitive, somente o `str_ireplace` é case-insensitive. O `Cc` é diferente de `cc`. Em geral, **blacklist não funcionam**. É muito mais fácil dizer o que é permitido do que listar tudo que é proibido!

Veja que isto:

```
function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

echo clean_string("BCC: fulano@email.com\r\n Cc: ciclano@email.com");
```

Retorná:

```
BCC: fulano@email.com Cc: ciclano@email.com
```

**Isto é INÚTIL.**

---

### Como proteger:

Não utilize o último argumento, nem irei mencionar ele aqui porque sinceramente nem sei como protege-lo. Entretanto o quarto argumento tem salvação, mas antes vou listar todos os erros que possui o código:

1. Falta de CSRF.
2. Não tratando o CRLF.
3. O texto da mensagem não está sendo tratada.

### 1. CSRF:

Adicione o CSRF-Token, simplesmente utilize um bom CSPRNG e salve-o na sessão, por exemplo:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['CSRF'])){
    $_SESSION['CSRF'] = unpack('H*', random_bytes(64))[1];
}
```

Depois acrescente:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CSRF" value="<?= $_SESSION['CSRF'] ?>">
```

Depois compare ambos os valores, que foi enviado e que está armazenado na sessão:

```
if(hash_equals($_SESSION['CSRF'], $_POST['CSRF']){
// O CSRF é igual!
}
```

Não utilize `===`, timing-attack. E obviamente não utilize o  `==`,  principalmente se utilizar um `json_decode`/`unserialize`, porque `"qualquer_coisa" == true` é sempre `true`, que foi o que fazia o [Laravel 4 (haha)](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/2lv1e2/csrf_vulnerability_in_laravel_4/).

### 2. Remover CRLF:

```
$email_from = str_ireplace(["\r", "\n", ':', ','], '', $email_from);
```

Dessa forma o meu código iria cair por replace abaixo. :'( Porque neste caso iria se tornar:

```
meu@email.comCcemail-de@outra-pessoa.com
```

*Acrescentei o `:` e `,` para que na pior das hipóteses disto fracassar e ambos não são valores válidos para caracteres de e-mail, até onde eu saiba.*

### 3. HTML:

A terceira questão é que seria ideal utilizar o `htmlentities`, dessa forma:

```
$email_message = htmlentities($email_message, ENT_QUOTES || ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
```

Isto iria assegurar que nenhuma mensagem iria possuir HTML, principalmente `<`, `>` para prevenir que inserirem um `<script>`, a mesma técnica para evitar XSS, os parametros utilizados são para definir qual a codificação utilizada, lembre-se que para que isto funcione também é preciso que determine a linguagem e o formato, por exemplo:

```
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

---

**No seu caso:**

> Requer PHP 7.0.0+

Acredito que isto seria suficiente para corrir os três casos acima, existem ainda melhorias possíveis, como verificar se realmente é um e-mail, se realmente é um número telefone e afins. Todas as edições que fiz estão comentadas no código.

```
<?php

session_start();

// Adicionado geração de CSRF-Token:
if (!isset($_SESSION['CSRF'])) {
    $_SESSION['CSRF'] = unpack('H*', random_bytes(64))[1];
}

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


// Adicionado comaparação de CSRF-Token e todos os campos são necessários serem preenchidos:
if (isset($_POST)
    && hash_equals($_POST['CSRF'], $_SESSION['CSRF'])
) {

    $email_to = "mail que recebe";
    $email_subject = "Mensagem vindo do site";


    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $telephone_from = $_POST['telephone'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $comments = $_POST['message'];

    // Adicionado remoção de CRLF:
    $email_from = str_ireplace(["\r", "\n", ':', ','], '', $email_from);

    $email_message = "Mensagem vindo do site\n\n";

    $email_message .= 'Name: ' . $first_name . "\n";
    $email_message .= 'Email Address: ' . $email_from . "\n";
    $email_message .= 'Telephone: ' . $telephone_from . "\n";
    $email_message .= 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n";
    $email_message .= 'Message: ' . $comments . "\n";

    // Adicionado htmlentitites para mensagem:
    $email_message = htmlentities($email_message, ENT_QUOTES || ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');

    // Adicionado Content-Type:
    $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

    ?>

<!-- Message sent! (change the text below as you wish)-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <div id="form_response" class="text-center">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="../imagens/thumbs/mail_sent.png" title="image" alt="imagem" />
                            <h1>Parabéns!</h1>
                            <p>Obrigado <b><?= htmlentities($first_name, ENT_QUOTES || ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8'); ?></b>, a sua mensagem foi enviada</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-theme" href="">Voltar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>                  
            </div>
    <!--End Message Sent-->

    <?php

}

?>

<form id="contact-form" action="contact.php" name="contactform" class="row" method="post">
    <div id="input_name" class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="name" class="form-control triggerAnimation animated"
               data-animate="bounceIn" placeholder="Nome">
    </div>
    <div id="input_telephone" class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" class="form-control triggerAnimation animated"
               data-animate="bounceIn" placeholder="Telefone">
    </div>
    <div id="input_email" class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control triggerAnimation animated"
               data-animate="bounceIn" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div id="input_subject" class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control triggerAnimation animated"
               data-animate="bounceIn" placeholder="Assunto">
    </div>
    <div id="input_message" class="col-md-12">
        <textarea class="form-control triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="bounceIn" name="message" id="comments"
                  rows="6" placeholder="Gostaria de ser contactado(a) para mais informações"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- Adicionado campo `CSRF` -->
    <input type="hidden" name="CSRF" value="<?= $_SESSION['CSRF'] ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Inkeliz entendi mais ou menos até porque não sou especializado mas se colocasse tudo junto seria mais fácil de entender. Em que parte devo substituir ou adicionar no meu php?

Comment: @Gcpt editei para acrescentar algo "tudo junto", se o formulário e o PHP estiverem na mesma página isto será suficiente.

Comment: eu agradeço a sua ajuda Inkeliz mas não está a funcionar e deixou de reenviar para a página de obrigado pelo seu contacto. Quando clica para enviar fica tudo branco. Qual o erro?

Comment: Veja nos logs do PHP, possivelmente está utilizando uma versão obsoleta (inferior ao PHP 5.6, ou seja uma versão insegura e que nem recebe atualizações de segurança) ou não está preenchendo todos os campos, em testes locais, com o PHP 7.1 no XAMPP, tudo está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Já atualizei de PHP 5.6 para 7.1, já fiz vários testes mas continua a não funcionar. Atualizei o trecho em html, pode ver (no final tem o recaptcha e trigger) Será por causa disso?

Comment: Ambas as partes do código estão na mesma página?

Comment: Pode ver aqui completo. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204380/como-corrigir-formul%C3%A1rio-de-contacto-seguro

Comment: Nos logs é apresentado algum problema? Coloque no inicio o trecho `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`, mude isto depois. Assim poderá ver o problema. Pode ser que esteja utilizando o BOM, por exemplo, impedindo o header de ser enviado. Testando exatamente o código, supondo que seja mesma página, retorna normalmente o "Parabéns!".  Se os arquivos estão em páginas distintas é necessário que gere um CSRF-Token em ambas as páginas.

Comment: Inkeliz O que fiz: No PHP selector alterei display_erros para On, no error_reporting alterei para E_ALL e log_erros para On. No htaccess coloquei "php_value error_reporting -1
php_flag display_errors On"... e no inicio do trecho o que você enviou. Utilizei o phpcoder para confirmar a syntax e está sem erros. Atualizei 7.1 e no metric do erros está limpa. Ainda assim não funciona. A página continua a ficar em branco sem reencaminhar para os agradecimentos (css e html inseridos na mesma página do contact.php). Algo está a bloquear o disparo mas não encontro o erro. No logs parece tudo normal...

Comment: @Gcpt fiz algumas modificações, eles estão funcionando normalmente. A única forma de "aparecer em braco" seria o CSRF-Token estando diferente ou não estiver enviando o cookie da sessão ou não está preenchendo todos os campos. Eu alterei este último caso, agora simplesmente enviado qualquer dado ele irá enviar.

Comment: Continua a não funcionar. Obrigado na mesma pela ajuda. Está tudo bem mas algo está a bloquear.

Comment: @ Inkeliz como te posso contactar por email? Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O PHP tem a função [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php) para filtrar conteúdos específicos.

No caso da função mail() é interessante usar FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING para o corpo e cabeçalhos e utilizar um FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL especificamente para os endereços de email de remetente, destinatário e outros.

É muito importante você ter claro o que deseja receber no email. Utilize a função [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php) para remover todo conteúdo HTML indesejado do corpo da mensagem ou, permitir somente um conjunto restrito de tags necessárias ao seu propósito, evitando assim que maliciosamente o usuário insira tags  no corpo do email. O que trataria especificamente o Cross Scripting.

Como em segurança é sempre melhor pecar por excesso, adicionei o comentário do @Inkeliz ao seu código, removendo as quebras de linha:

```
// limpa dados para o corpo da mensagem
function clean_string($string, $extra) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    $tags_permitidas = "<p><br>";

    if (is_array($extra)) {
        $bad = array_merge($bad, $extra);
    }

    $string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    return strip_tags(str_replace($bad,"",$string), $tags_permitidas);
}

// limpa dados para os cabeçalhos
function clean_string_eol($string) {
    return clean_string($string, array("\r", "\n"));
}                


$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string_eol($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email Address: ".filter_var($email_from, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string_eol($telephone_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string_eol($subject)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
```

Comment: Entendi a explicação. Vou experimentar e verificar o sitelock. Volto depois. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: O que o Gustavo sugeriu não está a funcionar. Continua a dar erro.